# Removing an object in java with only reference to it in an arraylist

Tags: java, object, arraylist, garbage-collection

I have an arrayList with an custom object:

```
public ArrayList<Mode> modes = new ArrayList<>();
```

That list has for example 3 instances in it. How would I set all those instances to be available for the garbage collector to remove them?

```
for (Mode mode : modes)
    mode = null;
```

The above does not work. My Eclipse (IDE) just says that the local variable mode is never used.
How would I get the actual instance to remove it?

Comment: Garbage collection is a transparent process. We never know when an object gets marked for collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just [clear the `ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clear--) to remove all the elements.

```
modes.clear();
```

Or use [its `Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#iterator--) and remove those you want.

Comment: Are all those instances in the array also set to null then? So that the garbage collector can remove them?

Comment: @Extremelyd1 You don't _set an instance to `null`_. You have to make the distinction between variables, values, and instances. `ArrayList#clear` will clear all references to the objects you've added to it. If those objects are no longer reachable (through other parts of your program), they will become candidates for garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `List.set` method to set individual elements to null.

```
for(int i=0;i<modes.size();++i)
    modes.set(i,null);
```

Use `List.clear()` to clear the entire array.

Or use an iterator to remove all elements:

```
Iterator<Mode> it = modes.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
    it.remove();
```